# How to get notified when crontab fails

Tags: bash, macos, cron

Trying to detect if my crontab job fails and if so I would want it to notify me but I could not find any information on that but the following from the old crontab.guru. What does the following mean?

`&& curl -sm 30 k.wdt.io/<email-address>/<cronjob-name>?c=`

Is there a good way to create a script in case crontab fails?

Using Mac OS

Comment: you add "MAILTO=your@email.com" in the first row

Comment: in the first row? you mean like this? 

```MAILTO=your@email.com /n
* * * * * echo 'hi' >> hi.txt```

Comment: @exactly, you will get notified by email if "hi" can not be written every minute to "hi.txt", but you need to have a MTA on your machine

Comment: How do I go about setting up a MTA?

Comment: first check if you have a MTA with `netstat -tlnp |grep :25` and post the output

Comment: on a debian like sytem you can install a MTA like this `sudo apt install ssmtp` and configure it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssmtp`

Comment: it tells me the following ```netstat: option requires an argument -- p```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crontab -e

```
MAILTO=your@email.com
* * * * * echo 'hi' >> hi.txt
```

please check if you have a MTA like this :

```
netstat -tlnp |grep :25
```

or using sudo

```
sudo netstat -tlnp |grep :25
```

and you should get a row like

```
root@linux:~# netstat -tlnp |grep :25
tcp    0    0    192.168.1.100:25    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    1322/master
```

if you do not get that then you install ssmtp

```
sudo apt install ssmtp
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssmtp
```

Comment: I got it installed using https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP since I was experiencing a "Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1" issue. What are the next steps in getting it configured?

Comment: then enter it without p like this : `netstat -tln |grep :25`

Comment: I get no output

Comment: I think I installed it incorrectly. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it works now. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

wdt.io was a cron job monitoring service. It was discontinued a while back.

The idea with the `&& curl` syntax is to run a HTTP request every time *after* your cron job completes successfully (with an exit status 0).

- If the cron job does not run at all (e.g. because the server is powered off) then obviously the curl call will not run
- If the cron job finished with a non-zero exit status, the part after `&&` will not be executed
- If server's network connection is down, then curl may attempt a HTTP request, but it will not reach the monitoring service

Either way, the idea with wdt.io was to check if it is receiving HTTP requests on a defined schedule. As soon as a request does not arrive on time, wdt.io would detect that and notify you.

This is a form of [Dead Man's Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch) and there is a number of SaaS offering this service. You can search the web for "cron job monitoring" and you will find them no problem :-)